# How can I update mapping for index in elasticsearch when I already have some field need add new fields without deleting index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with a few fields and I need to add a new field to the index without deleting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update an existing index using the
[Update mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#indices-put-mapping).

The following update mapping API request adds title, a new text field, to the publications index.

```
PUT /publications/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "title":  { "type": "text"}
  }
}
```